# pandas pivot table don't ignore 0

Tags: pandas, pivot

I'm building a basic pivot table. The data for the diploma column is 1,0 data (true/false). I wrote:

```
### High school name x # of Diplomas Annually 

pd.pivot_table(df, values='s_lasid', index=['hs_name1'],
               columns=['chrt_grad','diploma'], aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique()))
```

Right now, it is only counting where diploma = 1. How do I get it to also count where diploma = 0? 
[image]

Comment: Can you create some sample data of `df`, but not in picture, but in text?

Comment: Yep, editing the above post

Comment: You know what - I just realized I was looking at the wrong field. NVM!

Comment: Yes, I was a bit surprised not working ;)

Comment: Me too! Ha. I spent way too long trying to figure that out...